# Facebook API: can I get detailed info about user's location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I requests user's profile, the location has the following format

> Array ( [id] => 111227078906045 [name] => Some City, New York )

Is it possible to use that ID to retrieve full information about location, at least something like this

> Array ( [country] => United States [state] => New York [city] => Some City )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this ID in a request to the Graph API, i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/Place_ID` - that's all you can get from Facebook. The city and country are in the `name` field.

Comment: Well, it's not very helpful from facebook but anyway thank you very much!

Comment: Remember that information about places and similar is entered by the users, not Facebook stuff. Therefore, you should be careful when using it - I suggest you check what is returned by the Graph API for different cities so that you get an idea what challenges you might face.